# Service Intent - will it be caught by ActivityMonitor?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I want to monitor if a startService(...) call is being made in an Activity:

```
public void testShouldCallServiceOnSendButtonPress() throws Exception {
        assertNotNull(activity.pictureToSend);
        ActivityMonitor androidMock = help.mockIntent(1);
        TouchUtils.clickView(this, activity.sendButton);
        help.assertBehavior(androidMock);
    }

    public ActivityMonitor mockIntent(int numberOfExpectedIntentsSentToAndroid) {
        this.numberOfExpectedIntentsSentToAndroid = numberOfExpectedIntentsSentToAndroid;
        IntentFilter intentFilter = null;
        return androidMock = instrumentation.addMonitor(intentFilter, null, true);// catch all 
    }
```

above I'm adding a catch-all monitor (should catch both Activity and Service intents, right ?!)

```
assertNotNull( this.startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class)) );
```

above I verify that the service was started successfully, and it is.

But... the catch-all monitor is never hit, instrumentation.checkMonitorHit() is not >= 1.

Any ideas why ?

Comment: Is it possible the code is mocking you? ;)  Seriously though, have you tried monitoring for a specific Activity?  This might give you an idea if you are having more pervasive issues, or if it's a simple bugfix.

Comment: It mocks me all the time :) , and yes when testing for Intent with  MediaStore.ActionImageCapture beeing thrown, the monitor works, so...
Question Rephrase: ActivityMonitors should work for Services as well as for Activities, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Android source code, it seems that only Activity.startActivity is overriden with calls to Instrumentation. startService is not overriden in Activity, so it uses the default implementation from Context, so it never goes through the instrumentation.

So no, ActivityMonitor will not catch Service intents.

Comment: Thanks for digging into the source...you didn't happen to stumble over a ServiceMonitor by chance :-) ?

Comment: It's actually pretty easy to look at the source code if you install the [Android source code Eclipse plugin](http://code.google.com/p/adt-addons/).  


I find it easier to ctrl+click a method and check the source than to look through the docs.  


Unfortunately, I haven't seen any way to get a handle on Service.  


Perhaps if you could supply your own Application mock with startService overriden, then start services using getApplication().startService?